# "YARN" mode doesn't work into Hadoop YARN cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using Hadoop YARN and i configured my environment that is phisically composed by two subnet (composed by Access Point and one Station for each one) but i have a problem: when i set into "mapred-site.xml" the mapreduce.framework.name "yarn" it doesn't work: the execution gets stuck in the "running" state and after a long time the message "map 0% reduce 0%" appears and gets stuck again. If i use the "local" mode, the default one, it works perfectly.
The communication between each component has been configured and tested with ping and there should be no problem with this. I post my configuration files, thank you for the help.

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://giovanni-pc:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/data/nameNode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/data/dataNode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>1536</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <description>Max available cores data node.</description>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>1536</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>128</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>giovanni-pc</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
        <value>512</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
        <value>256</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
        <value>256</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**workers**

```
nodename1
nodename2
```

Comment: Are your node managers actually running? And registered to the resource manager? What command are you running to submit the job?

Comment: Yes, Nodes are registered int Resource Manager, I can see using yarn node -list. To submit jobs I use the classic "yarn jar ~/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.2.jar wordcount "books/*" output" to prove the application example, and now after a lot of minute i see the message:


**Container killed on request. Exit code is 143.**
**Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.**


Can the problem related to my RAM used? Is there a minimum RAM needed to use an Hadoop YARN cluster nodes?

Comment: Exit code 143 is memory related, but the values look okay at a glance...

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, i changed one of machines and it works, one of the last machines had too small RAM and it was impossible to allocate a container on it.

Comment: If you use Ambari to manage the cluster, it has the concept of config groups for different types of nodes, but in general, it's preferred to use the same server specs for all the nodes